# Excel label formatting uses cell formatting

Tags: excel, excel-2013, vba

I want to make my chart labels use the same formatting as their corresponding cells do.  (Cell text formating would do too.)

How should I approach this?

I already tried searching and looking at custom number features yet either did not help or I am a doofus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is pretty simple actually. I have done it for the first point. I am sure you can do it for the other as well :)

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ser As Series
    Dim pt As Point
    Dim dl As DataLabel

    Set ser = ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1)
    Set pt = ser.Points(1)
    Set dl = pt.DataLabel
    dl.Interior.ColorIndex = Sheets("Sample").Range("E8").Interior.ColorIndex
End Sub
```

[image]